# Adding fabric.js Lines to group

Tags: fabricjs

How do I add lines to group in fabric.js? It seems as if each line top and left property is set to 0, and because of that final size of grid is 0 as well.

Code of adding to group:

```
let group = new fabric.Group();

for (let i = 0; i < canvas.getWidth() / gridSize; i++) {

   let horizontalLine = new fabric.Line(
      [i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth()]
   );

   let verticalLine = new fabric.Line(
      [0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth(), i * gridSize]
   );

   group.add(horizontalLine, verticalLine);
}

canvas.add(group);
```

[Self-explaining fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/3efe2x9j/206/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be accomplished in the following way ...

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
let gridSize = 15;

$("#addAsGroup").click(() => {
    canvas.clear();
    let separateLines = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.getWidth() / gridSize; i++) {
        let horizontalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth()], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        let verticalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth(), i * gridSize], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        separateLines.push(horizontalLine);
        separateLines.push(verticalLine);
    }
    
    // add lines to group
    let group = new fabric.Group(separateLines);
    canvas.add(group);
});

$("#addAsSeparateObjects").click(() => {
    canvas.clear();
    let separateLines = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.getWidth() / gridSize; i++) {
        let horizontalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth()], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        let verticalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth(), i * gridSize], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        separateLines.push(horizontalLine);
        separateLines.push(verticalLine);
    }
    separateLines.forEach((line) => {
        canvas.add(line);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="addAsGroup">AddAsGroup</button>
<button id="addAsSeparateObjects">AddAsSeparateObjects</button>
```

Comment: It works, but performance is  too low. Do I really need to first add objects separately, and than add them to group?

Comment: @bartosz.baczek ah, my bad. I gave you a very complex solution. You should have said that earlier. Check updated answer. Hope everything works fine now :)

Comment: Well, thats just awesome ! Thank you very much. I guess when adding groups via constructor, it make some extra calculations, and group size changes. In the meantime I tried adding objects to group using addWithUpdate method, but with no luck either.